# How to get xml data from retrofit 2 and rxjava in android

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android, simple-framework

I am trying to get data from xml url and getting some problem.
Sample xml:

```
<company xmlns="http://www.test.com/test">
<person>
<pId>a11</pId>
<name>Mike</name>
<age>25</age>
<weight>82.7</weight>
<profile>www.test.com/mike.jpb</profile>
<person>
<person>
<pId>a11</pId>
<name>Mike</name>
<age>25</age>
<weight>82.7</weight>
<profile>www.test.com/mike.jpb</profile>
<person>
<person>
<pId>a11</pId>
<name>Mike</name>
<age>25</age>
<weight>82.7</weight>
<profile>www.test.com/mike.jpb</profile>
<person>
</company>
```

what I have done in my java code:

```
Observable<List<Person>> call = APIClient.getRetrofitAPIClient().getPerson(APIClient.API_PARAMETER);
        subscription = call
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // optional if you do not wish to override the default behavior
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Person>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        if (e instanceof HttpException) {
                            HttpException response = (HttpException)e;
                            int code = response.code();
                            Log.e("TOTAL", "code "+code);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Person> p) {
                        showResults(p);
                    }
                });
```

Now

```
public interface APIService {

    @GET("/{paramter}")
    rx.Observable<List<Person>> getPersons(@Path("paramter") String paramter);
}
```

and

```
// get retrofit api services
    public static  APIService getRetrofitAPIClient(){
        if(apiService == null){
            Retrofit retrofit =new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJavaCallAdapterFactory)
                    .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        }
        return  apiService;
    }
```

Model classes

```
@Root(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Element(name = "pId")
    private String pId;

    @Element(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Element(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @Element(name="weight")
    private double weight;

   @Element(name="profile")
    private String profile;
}
```

and

```
@Root(name = "company")
public class Company {
    @ElementList(entry = "person", inline = true)
    private List<Person> companies;
}
```

I am getting following in logcat:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{co.test/co.test.activity.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for
>   java.util.List for method APIService.getPerson

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using RxJava2 ?

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXmlConverterFactory doesn't support List, you need to define the API interface result as an array of Person:

```
public interface APIService {

     @GET("/{paramter}")
    rx.Observable<Person[]> getPersons(@Path("paramter") String paramter);
}
```

see SimpleXmlConverterFactory class [documentation](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-converters/simplexml/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/simplexml/SimpleXmlConverterFactory.java):

> This converter only applies for class types. **Parameterized types**
>   (e.g., {@code **List**}) are  * not handled.